# Can't change the flash file later with swfobject

Tags: javascript, swfobject

I use swfobject to load a youtube embedded video, it works nice, but when i try to load another youtube video after a specific time it doesn't work, It looks like the container div is totally replaced with the swf instead of putting it inside it.

Note: i attempt using `swfobject.embedSWF(path,divID,width,height)` to load other videos which doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: You will probably need to show some code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SWFObject v2.x replaces the target HTML element with an `<object>`.

If you want to use the same target element for multiple SWF embeds, you'll need to re-create the target element before attempting your subsequent embed. [Here's a link to a tutorial for this topic](http://learnswfobject.com/advanced-topics/load-a-swf-using-javascript-onclick-event/) (scroll down to "Replacing a loaded SWF with another SWF").

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older post, but just thought I'd mention that I ended up just using the [YouTube javascript API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Queueing_Functions) to switch the video. Simpler, and the transition looks cleaner than trying to remove the object and add another one.

Comment: this is the best approach, because the YouTube player only switches out the video assets, and doesn't re-load the entire player mechanism each time.